# Making a new list from existing list in flutter; changes both list upon action on new list

Tags: list, flutter, dart, flutter-onpressed

i am making a list in flutter from an existing list and when i used this new list and perform some action on it like change its quantity parameter it changes the parameter of existing list also. Can some one tell me where i am going wrong.

**Existing list:**

```
  List<ItemsModel> originalList=[
    ItemsModel(name: 'High Quality Double Spring Tummy Trimmer For Unisex',quantity: '30'),
    ItemsModel(name: 'High Quality Double Spring Tummy Trimmer For Unisex',quantity: '30'),
    ItemsModel(name: 'High Quality Double Spring Tummy Trimmer For Unisex',quantity: '30'),
  ];
```

**New list:**

```
  List<ItemsModel> updatedItemList;
      void initState() {
        updatedItemList=[];
        originalList.forEach((val){
      updatedItemList.add(val);
    });
        super.initState();
      }
```

**on pressed button:**

```
 updatedItemList[i].quantity=qtyReceive
```

And on some button pressed i am performing this action that was updating both lists. Why??

Comment: Both lists store references to the same `ItemsModel` objects.  Mutations to those objects will be reflected in both lists.  If you want them to be independent, you'll need to make a *deep* copy, which will require creating new `ItemsModel` instances.

Comment: How can i make that one in my case?

Comment: You would have to look at the documentation for whatever your `ItemsModel` class is.

Comment: as @jamesdlin mentioned we can create the new objects based  on the original list items. Added an example below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @jamesdlin mentioned, creating a deep copy will solve the issue by change reference to new `ItemsModel` `object`s in the `list`.

Small example of creating deep copy:

```
class ItemsModel{
  String name;
  String quantity;
  ItemsModel({this.name,this.quantity});
}


void main() {
   List<ItemsModel> originalList=[
    ItemsModel(name: 'High Quality Double Spring Tummy Trimmer For Unisex',quantity: '30'),
    ItemsModel(name: 'High Quality Double Spring Tummy Trimmer For Unisex',quantity: '30'),
    ItemsModel(name: 'High Quality Double Spring Tummy Trimmer For Unisex',quantity: '30'),
  ];

  List<ItemsModel> updatedItemList;
  updatedItemList=[];
  originalList.forEach((val){
      //creating new ItemsModel objects and adding to the updatedList
      updatedItemList.add(ItemsModel(name:val.name,quantity:val.quantity));
    });

  print('Original List');
  for(var listItem in originalList){
    listItem.quantity = '60';
    print('${listItem.name},${listItem.quantity}');
  }

  print('Updated List');
    for(var listItem in updatedItemList){
    print('${listItem.name},${listItem.quantity}');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I am late to the party, but anyways this can help someone else who come here
Solution- Use

```
myList = List.from(mynewlist);
```

instead of

```
mylist = mynewlist;
```

Comment: The "from" method does a copy of the List but does not perform a deep copy as the question intended.